# Keeping score in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I have an app which tests students' knowledge.  After each unit, it transitions to an overall level view controller which I would like to keep score of how many units are complete.  What would be the best way of doing this?  I would like to present the results in a table view if possible.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code of attempts you've made? We aren't going to write your app for you - if you show some level of research and effort has been made (and show some code samples) you will get much better results...

Comment: I've tried passing strings from the first controller to the overall one, building an array and displaying that.  That has yielded some positive results, I was just wondering if there were better ways to do it.  I've checked quite a few questions on here, but a lot of them relate to games and java...

Comment: Java or Cocoa? Post some code so we can see what you have so far.

Comment: Cocoa.  It's not really a case of needing code, I'm just looking for ideas that people may have used in a similar position.  I should be able to write the code ok; just out for some advice really :)

Comment: You're definitely going to have to give a specific problem you're having or question you have. Your "question" is way too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, as the commenters have said, is rather vague, so I will only offer general advice. In the class (or classes) where you test the students knowledge, you need to have some method that passes the name of that unit, and presumably a score, to the overall level view controller.  There are a bunch of ways that this could be done.  One way would be to post a notification with the NSNotificationCenter method postNotificationName:object:userInfo:. The userInfo could include the name of the unit, the score, and any other info you want. The overall level controller would register as an observer of that notification.  The same notification could be sent from other classes, if you have a different class for each unit. The controller would then take the info in the notification and add it to an array which would be the data source for your table view.

Comment: Yes I've realised my mistake as my reputation has taken quite a hit with that one!!  Your answer is really all I wanted, examples of ways to keep score of different units (themselves stored within view controllers).  I shall research NSNotificationCenter so thanks for pointing me in the right direction!